# Unable to copy SOME files from old hard disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, permissions, hard-drive

**Why and what I am trying to do:**

I am unable to copy some files from my old hard disk. The old hard-disk has windows installed, but they are crashing and I am unable to start them. On the same computer on a second hard disk I have Ubuntu installed. I am trying from inside the Ubuntu to copy the files over so that I can format the hard disk. Now I have successfully copied folders like "Downloads" and "Desktop" but folders in the main hard disk like xampp htdocs folder, I am unable to copy for some reason.

**What I have tried:**

I have made `chmod 777 -r` for the entire hard disk in order to make sure permission is not an issue.

I have launched `gksu nautilous` utility with admin permission from Ubuntu

**The error I get for some files:**

> `Error splicing file:Permission denied.`

`fdisk -l` output

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x16aec885

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *      2048    206847    204800  100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       206848 625139711 624932864  298G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. I still get an error

Comment: It is one specific folder for some reason and that is the htdocs folder for xampp. I tried to compress it and use various techniques around actually copying them. I can move it locally freely.

Comment: I also tried to use command line with `sudo cp`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do when you wanted to copy those files and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8xSA34Wb

Comment: Hello David, I think it is pretty clear that I tried to copy them through various methods and they all yielded the same outcome which is an error message that says `Error splicing file:Permission denied.` for some of the files only.

Comment: Run `sudo ntfsfix -n /dev/sdb2`  with `-n` for no action, just check the status.

Comment: `Refusing to operate on a read-write mounted device /dev/sdb2`
I also tried to cd /dev/sdb2 and wasn't able to. I am able to access the hard drive through /media/"long-identifier"

Comment: Yeah, you have to unmount it. `sudo umount  /dev/sdb2`

Comment: My bad. 

`Mounting volume OK....
NTFS volume version is 3.1.`

Everything else I omitted shows successful and OK

Comment: @NinjaStars Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/854345/edit) your question to add any additional info, like the output from `fdisk -l`.

Comment: It is there now. Do you guys need any additional information?

Comment: @NinjaStars, Does it stop in specific file or any thing from that folder even subfiles? Try renaming then moving it?  Use `sudp cp -r -v .. ..` for verbose output . post the output.  It could be a problem EXT4 side, could you try copy to a flash disk with same  file system NTFS.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wegY8kX3

Comment: @NinjaStars, Did you find a solution to this one?

Comment: No, I think the files are corrupted and being shown as locked. Which doesn't make sense because they are the only files that have this problem in the entire hard disk. :/